# magento 2 Estimate Shipping rate not updating

Tags: shipping, magento-2.1.2

I am new in Magento 2.

I used Magento 2.1.2 with custom theme. When I add product in cart than select/change country and state Estimate Shipping Rate not updating. Ajax does not call `estimate-shipping-methods` controller.

Following `checkout_cart_index.xml` for Estimate Shipping and Tax.

```
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="cart/shipping.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="types" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="form.input" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="summary-block-config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="shipping-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <!--Step configuration components-->
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                    <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">summary-block-config</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-rates" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-rates</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="block-shipping" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart/shipping-estimation</item>
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="address-fieldsets" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">address-fieldsets</item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.city</item>
                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">110</item>
                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.country_id</item>
                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">112</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                            </item>
                                            <!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
                                            <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
                                                <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                        <!-- The following items override configuration of corresponding address attributes -->
                                        <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!-- Make region attribute invisible on frontend. Corresponding input element is created by region_id field -->
                                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">111</item>
                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.postcode</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
                                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="checkoutProvider" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: Any solutions about that?